# Is it necessary to set ValidateIssuerSigningKey to true when using HMAC256 for verifying JWT Token?

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using AspNet Core to build a web api and JWT tokens to authenticate users.

I see that in `TokenValidationParameters` the default value of `ValidateIssuerSigningKey` property is false.

Does it make any difference if we set it to true, when using the **HMAC256** Symmetric key to sign and verify tokens (where there is no public-key added to the token like in case of RSA)?

```
    services
        .AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            cfg.SaveToken = true;
            string jwtIssuer = configuration["JwtIssuer"];
            SymmetricSecurityKey securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(configuration["JwtKey"]));
            cfg.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidIssuer = jwtIssuer,
                ValidAudience = jwtIssuer,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = securityKey,
                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
            };
        });
```

Or is it necessary to set `ValidateIssuerSigningKey` to true only when using RSA keys?

Here is the code level documentation of this property:

```
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Gets or sets a boolean that controls if validation of the Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityKey
    //     that signed the securityToken is called.
    //
    // Remarks:
    //     It is possible for tokens to contain the public key needed to check the signature.
    //     For example, X509Data can be hydrated into an X509Certificate, which can be used
    //     to validate the signature. In these cases it is important to validate the SigningKey
    //     that was used to validate the signature.
    [DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool ValidateIssuerSigningKey { get; set; }
```

Comment: You validate issuer when you want to check/test the token was issued by an allowed server, if you don't validate the issuer anyone with the signing key can create a token that will be valid against your server

Comment: @saj Are you speaking about `ValidateIssuerSigningKey` or `ValidateIssuer` property? The latter is `true` by default and so I am validating the issuer.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 3):

Based on looking at the Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens source code, I could find only one place where the ValidateIssuerSigningKey boolean property is used, here:

https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens/Validators.cs

Which ultimately causes this code block to be executed:

```
    X509SecurityKey x509SecurityKey = securityKey as X509SecurityKey;
    if (x509SecurityKey?.Certificate is X509Certificate2 cert)
    {
        DateTime utcNow = DateTime.UtcNow;
        var notBeforeUtc = cert.NotBefore.ToUniversalTime();
        var notAfterUtc = cert.NotAfter.ToUniversalTime();

        if (notBeforeUtc > DateTimeUtil.Add(utcNow, validationParameters.ClockSkew))
            throw LogHelper.LogExceptionMessage(new SecurityTokenInvalidSigningKeyException(LogHelper.FormatInvariant(LogMessages.IDX10248, notBeforeUtc, utcNow)));

        LogHelper.LogInformation(LogMessages.IDX10250, notBeforeUtc, utcNow);

        if (notAfterUtc < DateTimeUtil.Add(utcNow, validationParameters.ClockSkew.Negate()))
            throw LogHelper.LogExceptionMessage(new SecurityTokenInvalidSigningKeyException(LogHelper.FormatInvariant(LogMessages.IDX10249, notAfterUtc, utcNow)));

        LogHelper.LogInformation(LogMessages.IDX10251, notAfterUtc, utcNow);
    }
```

I.e. that flag relates to X509 certificates only, and the testing of the time period they are valid for. So I suspect it does not affect tokens validated using HMAC256... unless the HMAC key was obtained from an X509 certificate!

Answer (score 3):

The Azure Active Directory people clarify this on this GitHub Wiki page created in December 2020:

https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/wiki/Use-of-TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuerSigningKey

I'll quote key parts for convenience:

> Normally this [`ValidateIssuerSigningKey`] is not required because the user / runtime must set `IssuerSigningKey` or `IssuerSigningKeys` or in the case of custom security key retrieval the delegate `IssuerSigningKeyResolver` ( Definition ) for keys to be available for validating the signature on the token. ... It is assumed that only keys from trusted sources are set.

> If you need custom validation of the security key that signed the token you can ... set `TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuerSigningKey` to true. ...
> The default behavior is applicable to X509SecurityKey and checks that the certificate is not expired. No CRL or other checks are made.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. With "only keys from trusted sources" do you mean there are some built-in OS security keys, which are used as private keys to sign JWTs?

Comment: @AlexanderFarber I'm not an Azure Active Directory user, I just pointed to the answer from the AAD people. It seems (but I might be wrong) that in AAD (not the OS) it is like this: The JWT signer with their private key and the JWT validator exist as two different parties in a system connected to AAD. Now when the validating party needs to validate a JWT, then setting 'ValidateIssuerSigningKey' invokes an AAD mechanism that additionally checks if the signing key's certificate is still valid.